# trying to create additional child tasks form task operation

Tags: airflow

I have an Airflow dag that runs a Python operation.

In the Python operator I query against a DB and get a result (let's say 1,2,3...8 things that need to be run), sometimes you might run none, sometimes you might run up to 10.

within the Python operator I tried to create new operators and chain them to the dag.

e.g.

```
   currentDag = context['dag']
   current_task_instance = context['task_instance']
   for itemToProcess in itemsToProcess:
         newTask = LivyOperator( task_id = unique id, ..., dag = currentDag)
```

but unfortunately, the new tasks do not seem to get scheduled.
I tried adding

```
newTask.set_downstream(newTask)
```

this threw an exception saying `AttributeError: 'TaskInstance' object has no attribute 'update_relative'`

I don't want to create a new dag since it's only a few tasks that I want to run. I want to only show the dags if possible under the current dag.

How can I chain a new operator to be spun up from a current operator?

Comment: could you share the `DAG` example with `EmptyOperator`s?